# Listen for HTML rendering process events

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm reading some articles about the rendering process:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/
http://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-critical-rendering-path/

I would like to be able to listen for events of the steps occuring during the rendering process, to be able to know when the browser starts (and finish) to process a HTML document, when a css rule is added to the CSSOM tree,...

Actually, I'm looking for the informations displayed in the [devtools timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline), but in a formal format.

I do not think that there is a standardized model, but may be some browser are allowing to listen for these events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use readonly properties from [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing), IDL interface:

```
interface PerformanceTiming {
  readonly attribute unsigned long long navigationStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long unloadEventStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long unloadEventEnd;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long redirectStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long redirectEnd;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long fetchStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long domainLookupStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long domainLookupEnd;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long connectStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long connectEnd;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long secureConnectionStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long requestStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long responseStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long responseEnd;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long domLoading;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long domInteractive;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long domContentLoadedEventStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long domContentLoadedEventEnd;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long domComplete;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long loadEventStart;
  readonly attribute unsigned long long loadEventEnd;
};
```

It full [description from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming).

But you can't listen changing of `performance.timing` object.

Comment: Thank you, it is what I was looking for. But what do you mean by _"you can't listen changing of performance.timing object"_?